# Usage of correct prepositions

Tags: grammar

It it more correct to say “solution of an assignment” or “solution to an assignment”

Comment: This could entirely depend on context. Please could you provide the full sentence, and circumstances. "Assignments" do not always have, nor call for "solutions". The words do not stand in natural juxtaposition such as for example "question" and "answer", "seek" and "find" etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from a comparison of the [Google results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=solution+to+an+assignment%2Csolution+of+an+assignment&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csolution%20to%20an%20assignment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csolution%20of%20an%20assignment%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csolution%20to%20an%20assignment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csolution%20of%20an%20assignment%3B%2Cc0), neither is "more correct" than the other. Let's notice that the recorded use is always "solution of/to an assignment problem".

To boot, if we have a look at the usage of "solution of/to a problem" ([Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=solution+to+a+problem%2Csolution+of+a+problem&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csolution%20to%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csolution%20of%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csolution%20to%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csolution%20of%20a%20problem%3B%2Cc0)) it can be inferred that the preference for "of" from days gone by has merely been replaced by a rather recent preference for "to". Here too, there is no significant difference, and the matter being very similar, there is then even more ground to think that there is no difference in the case of the word "assignment".